# how to add product to reductionOrder from apex test class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, order, orderitem

I created a testClass that inserts an originalOrder with a product of a quantity : 4.
Then, i created a reduction order related to the OriginalOrder. Now, I tried to add product to the reductionOrder but i couldn't insert the products.
I'm having this Error:
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: ENTITY_IS_LOCKED, Unable to modify activated Order:  cannot delete Order, or add or remove Order Products: []
Class.TestDataFactory.createOrderItems: line 79

Does anyone know why i'm having this ERROR ? how can I add product to a reductionOrder ?
[image]

This is the DataFactory
[image]

need Help plz !

Comment: Welcome to SFSE; Please see [ask]. Please don't post screenshots of your code - rather, use the code editing tools in [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but check your TestDataFactory.createReductionOrder method to see if it's activating the order (StatusCode='Activated').

If not, check for any triggers that might be activating it automatically.